# Why date field is not stored into the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, psql

I couldn't store the date field value to the database.I use the datepicker option for selecting the date.I can store the date when it is initialized in the model.

Rails console for saving the data is given below:

```
Started POST "/folders" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-14 16:55:17 +0530
Processing by FoldersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Lflnh4FTwyLdkiSXHvXnzmnTNYwpxIFk1uHl7byXoIPeVaFv2I8ehvZrYx1g8koKnwzYcKJ9zftiHao6x9Grug==", "commit"=>"Save", "folder"=>{"folder_date"=>"2015-10-14", "client_id"=>"5", "employee_id"=>"5", "priority"=>"Normal", "requirements"=>"", "additional_requirements"=>"", "estimated_cost"=>"", "expected_date"=>"10/31/2015", "attachments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"remote_attachment_url"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "notes"=>""}}
```

Folders controller is below:

```
class FoldersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_folder, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def table
    @folders = Folder.includes(:client).includes(:employee).all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: FoldersDatatable.new(view_context, @folders) }
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def assign_index
    @folder = Folder.find(params[:folder_id])
  end

  def assignment
    @folder = Folder.find(params[:folder_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :assignment}
    end
  end

  def assign
    respond_to do |format|
      if @folder.update(folder_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, notice: 'Folder was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @folder }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @folder.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def new
    @folder = Folder.new
    @folder.attachments.build
  end

  def edit
    @folder.attachments.build unless @folder.attachments.present?
  end

  def create
    @folder = Folder.new(folder_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @folder.save
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, notice: 'Folder was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @folder }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @folder.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @folder.update(folder_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, notice: 'Folder was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @folder }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @folder.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @folder.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to folders_url, notice: 'Folder was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def select
    @folders = Folder.where(id: "#{params[:id]}") if params[:id].present?
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: FoldersSelect.new(@folders, params) }
    end
  end

  def cancel
    @folder = Folder.find params[:folder_id]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @folder.canceled!
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, notice: "Folder was successfully cancelled" }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, notice: "Folder was not cancelled" }
      end
    end
  end

  def close
    @folder = Folder.find params[:folder_id]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @folder.closed!
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, notice: "Folder was successfully closed" }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, notice: "Folder was not closed" }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @folder.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to folders_url, notice: 'Folder was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def reviewed
    @folder = Folder.find params[:folder_id]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @folder.reviewed!
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, notice: 'Folder is reviewed' }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, alert: 'Folder status update to reviewed failed due to errors.' }
      end
    end
  end

  def accepted
    @folder = Folder.find params[:folder_id]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @folder.accepted!
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, notice: 'Folder is accepted' }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, alert: 'Folder status update to accepted failed due to errors.' }
      end
    end
  end

  def in_progress
    @folder = Folder.find params[:folder_id]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @folder.in_progress!
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, notice: 'Folder is in_progress' }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, alert: 'Folder status update to in_progress failed due to errors.' }
      end
    end
  end

  def wait_approval
    @folder = Folder.find params[:folder_id]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @folder.wait_approval!
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, notice: 'Folder is wait_approval' }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, alert: 'Folder status update to wait_approval failed due to errors.' }
      end
    end
  end

  def wait_comp
    @folder = Folder.find params[:folder_id]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @folder.wait_comp!
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, notice: 'Folder is wait_comp' }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, alert: 'Folder status update to wait_comp failed due to errors.' }
      end
    end
  end

  def outsourced
    @folder = Folder.find params[:folder_id]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @folder.outsourced!
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, notice: 'Folder is outsourced' }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, alert: 'Folder status update to outsourced failed due to errors.' }
      end
    end
  end

  def completed
    @folder = Folder.find params[:folder_id]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @folder.completed!
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, notice: 'Folder is completed' }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, alert: 'Folder status update to completed failed due to errors.' }
      end
    end
  end

  def abandoned
    @folder = Folder.find params[:folder_id]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @folder.abandoned!
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, notice: 'Folder is abandoned' }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, alert: 'Folder status update to abandoned failed due to errors.' }
      end
    end
  end

  def pending
    @folder = Folder.find params[:folder_id]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @folder.payment_pending!
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, notice: 'Folder is in payment pending' }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, alert: 'Folder status update to payment pending failed due to errors.' }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def set_folder
      @folder = Folder.find(params[:id])
    end

    def folder_params
      params.require(:folder).permit(:code, :organization_id, :client_id, :vendor_id, :employee_id, :kind, :folder_date, :item, :owner, :assigned_employee_id, :assigned_date,
                                    :party, :status, :notes, :active, :archived, :requirements, :additional_requirements, :priority, :item_name, :item_parts,
                                    :owner_name, :owner_phone, :owner_email, :party_name, :party_phone, :party_email, :estimated_cost, :expected_date,
                                     attachments_attributes: [:id, :organization_id, :attachable_type, :attachable_id,
                                                             :attachment, :remote_attachment_url],
                                     components_attributes: [:id, :organization_id, :vendor_id, :folder_id, :default, :kind, :name, :reference, :properties, :status, :notes, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

Complete log is given below:

```
Started GET "/clients/select.json?s=a&per=10" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-15 10:18:34 +0530
Processing by ClientsController#select as JSON
  Parameters: {"s"=>"a", "per"=>"10"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Client Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE (clients.name ilike '%a%')  ORDER BY clients.name LIMIT 10
  Address Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."addressable_id" = $1 AND "addresses"."addressable_type" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["addressable_id", 1], ["addressable_type", "Client"]]
  Phone Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "phones".* FROM "phones" WHERE "phones"."callable_id" = $1 AND "phones"."callable_type" = $2  ORDER BY "phones"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["callable_id", 1], ["callable_type", "Client"]]
  Address Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."addressable_id" = $1 AND "addresses"."addressable_type" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["addressable_id", 5], ["addressable_type", "Client"]]
  Phone Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "phones".* FROM "phones" WHERE "phones"."callable_id" = $1 AND "phones"."callable_type" = $2  ORDER BY "phones"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["callable_id", 5], ["callable_type", "Client"]]
  Address Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."addressable_id" = $1 AND "addresses"."addressable_type" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["addressable_id", 4], ["addressable_type", "Client"]]
  Phone Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "phones".* FROM "phones" WHERE "phones"."callable_id" = $1 AND "phones"."callable_type" = $2  ORDER BY "phones"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["callable_id", 4], ["callable_type", "Client"]]
  Address Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."addressable_id" = $1 AND "addresses"."addressable_type" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["addressable_id", 3], ["addressable_type", "Client"]]
  Phone Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "phones".* FROM "phones" WHERE "phones"."callable_id" = $1 AND "phones"."callable_type" = $2  ORDER BY "phones"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["callable_id", 3], ["callable_type", "Client"]]
Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 10.1ms | ActiveRecord: 3.5ms)


Started GET "/employees/select.json?s=e&per=10" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-15 10:18:37 +0530
Processing by EmployeesController#select as JSON
  Parameters: {"s"=>"e", "per"=>"10"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Employee Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "employees".* FROM "employees" WHERE (employees.name ilike '%e%')  ORDER BY employees.name LIMIT 10
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 1.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)


Started POST "/folders" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-15 10:18:47 +0530
Processing by FoldersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"6LTvSiLk2KDZzuNctei3Y8LmB7AaxBPw5SWWaCzVNvobGCmiezgFBPI3pNbL7xqnNDnqTJF9X29R2dm/V5M9ww==", "commit"=>"Save", "folder"=>{"folder_date"=>"2015-10-15", "client_id"=>"5", "employee_id"=>"1", "priority"=>"Normal", "requirements"=>"", "additional_requirements"=>"", "estimated_cost"=>"", "expected_date"=>"10/30/2015", "attachments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"remote_attachment_url"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "notes"=>""}}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Unpermitted parameter: _destroy
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Protokoll::Models::CustomAutoIncrement Load (163.8ms)  SELECT  "custom_auto_increments".* FROM "custom_auto_increments" WHERE "custom_auto_increments"."counter_model_name" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["counter_model_name", "folder"]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "custom_auto_increments" SET "counter" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "custom_auto_increments"."id" = $3  [["counter", 60], ["updated_at", "2015-10-15 04:48:47.918273"], ["id", 4]]
  SQL (17.7ms)  INSERT INTO "folders" ("client_id", "employee_id", "folder_date", "notes", "requirements", "additional_requirements", "priority", "status", "created_at", "updated_at", "code") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11) RETURNING "id"  [["client_id", 5], ["employee_id", 1], ["folder_date", "2015-10-15"], ["notes", ""], ["requirements", ""], ["additional_requirements", ""], ["priority", "Normal"], ["status", "opened"], ["created_at", "2015-10-15 04:48:47.747063"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-15 04:48:47.747063"], ["code", "F00060"]]
  SQL (111.9ms)  INSERT INTO "versions" ("event", "whodunnit", "created_at", "item_id", "item_type") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["event", "create"], ["whodunnit", "1"], ["created_at", "2015-10-15 04:48:47.747063"], ["item_id", 60], ["item_type", "Folder"]]
  SQL (7.1ms)  INSERT INTO "attachments" ("attachment", "attachable_type", "attachable_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["attachment", nil], ["attachable_type", "Folder"], ["attachable_id", 60], ["created_at", "2015-10-15 04:48:48.095467"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-15 04:48:48.095467"]]
   (27.4ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/folders/60
Completed 302 Found in 397ms (ActiveRecord: 332.9ms)


Started GET "/folders/60" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-15 10:18:48 +0530
Processing by FoldersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"60"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Folder Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "folders".* FROM "folders" WHERE "folders"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 60]]
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)) OR ((roles.name = 'manager') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 1]]
  Rendered shared/actions/_actions.html.haml (4.9ms)
  Client Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  Address Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."addressable_id" = $1 AND "addresses"."addressable_type" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["addressable_id", 5], ["addressable_type", "Client"]]
  Phone Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "phones".* FROM "phones" WHERE "phones"."callable_id" = $1 AND "phones"."callable_type" = $2  ORDER BY "phones"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["callable_id", 5], ["callable_type", "Client"]]
  Email Load (2.6ms)  SELECT  "emails".* FROM "emails" WHERE "emails"."emailable_id" = $1 AND "emails"."emailable_type" = $2  ORDER BY "emails"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["emailable_id", 5], ["emailable_type", "Client"]]
  Employee Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "employees".* FROM "employees" WHERE "employees"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Component Load (21.8ms)  SELECT "components".* FROM "components" WHERE "components"."folder_id" = $1  [["folder_id", 60]]
  Employee Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "employees".* FROM "employees"
  PaperTrail::Version Load (23.5ms)  SELECT "versions".* FROM "versions" WHERE "versions"."item_id" = $1 AND "versions"."item_type" = $2  ORDER BY "versions"."created_at" ASC, "versions"."id" ASC, id asc  [["item_id", 60], ["item_type", "Folder"]]
  Rendered folders/show.html.haml within layouts/application (133.7ms)
  Role Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 1]]
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'manager') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.haml (3.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_flash.html.haml (0.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 384ms (Views: 324.8ms | ActiveRecord: 53.4ms)
```

Comment: Please show your `FoldersController`. Have you whitelisted the params?

Comment: Which date value is not saving? `folder_date` or `expected_date`?

Comment: expected_date is not saving

Comment: I suspect the format is not correct. Change it to `yyyy/mm/dd` and try again

Comment: paste your complete logs

Comment: Solved it by adding the format option with javascript :)

Comment: Here is the older javascript code:

Comment: // datepicker
  $('.datepicker-input').datepicker({
      todayBtn: "linked",
      todayHighlight: true
  });

Comment: Datepicker javascript with date format option is given in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved by using the date format with datepicker javascript.

```
  // datepicker
  $('.datepicker-input').datepicker({
      todayBtn: "linked",
      todayHighlight: true,
      format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
  });
```